# EWS Api gives timeout and (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm using the following code to get calendar appointments from my Office 365 account with EWS api's set (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2.0):

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mail, password);
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
Folder DefaultCalendar = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(fromDate, toDate);
FindItemsResults<Appointment> resultAppointments = Folder.FindAppointments(calendarView);
```

often the application crash with the following exceptions:

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The
>   request failed. The operation has timed out --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest&
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder(FolderId
>   folderId, PropertySet propertySet)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder[TFolder](FolderId
>   folderId, PropertySet propertySet)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarFolder.Bind(ExchangeService
>   service, FolderId id)

or:

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The
>   request failed. The remote server returned an error: (503) Server
>   Unavailable. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned
>   an error: (503) Server Unavailable.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest&
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder(FolderId
>   folderId, PropertySet propertySet)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder[TFolder](FolderId
>   folderId, PropertySet propertySet)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarFolder.Bind(ExchangeService
>   service, FolderId id)

or:

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The
>   request failed. The underlying connection was closed: A connection
>   that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A
>   connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the
>   server.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest&
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1
>   parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString,
>   ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling
>   errorHandlingMode)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder.InternalFindItems[TItem](SearchFilter
>   searchFilter, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarFolder.FindAppointments(CalendarView
>   view)

or:

> The server cannot service this request right now. Try again later.

It seems that sometimes Office 365 services are unreachable or on throttling; I tried to try-catch my code, but the application still crash; I think because a new Thread is opened. How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place to start is to get the latest version of the EWS Managed API from Github https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api . The version you using hasn't been update since 2015 which is when Microsoft stopped releasing compiled versions of that library. However the code has been updated with numerous bug fixes on GitHub

With the code your using I would suggest you always set the X-AnchorMailBox which can cause 503 and timeout issues see
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2015/05/11/best-practices-ews-authentication-and-access-issues/ (even if your not using Impersonation)

Depending on how much work your application is doing you may get throttled its important in that case to process the exception and retry. Also with Office365 mailboxes get moved around a fair bit on the back-end so it can be common to see period where the Mailbox is inaccessible during these moves

> > I tried to try-catch my code, but the application still crash; I think because a new Thread is opened. How can I handle this issue?

No it doesn't span a new thread you can check the source yourself on GitHub so you must have another issue with your exception handling.