# Create appointments in other uses' calendars using EWS sometimes fails because server is not available

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

About 1 year ago, my task was to create appointments in my companies users' calendars using powershell/EWS. I was lucky and found a script on the www that really worked well (Codes below). The script imports several CSV files and creates 1 appointment for each line in the CSVs. The script ran for months without any issues. But in the last weeks, the script kept on failing. But it doesn't fail all the time. Sometimes it is enough to restart it. Sometimes it needs 3 or 4 restarts. It doesn't fail at the same file and - as said - it doesn't always fail. So I guess the script as well as the processed data has to be valid.

When the script fails, it mostly says something like "The request failed. The remote server returned an error (503). Server not available." The error is not always the same, but it is always about a failed connection to the exchange server. In many cases, the popup window where I should enter my credentials for exchange online is displayed. But obviously I entered these credentials before (import of encrypted password). So I think the connection breaks down and so I'm asked to re-enter them.

There is no firewall or AV blocking the connection. There are no interruptions of my internet connection...

My question is:
At the moment, when the error occurs, powershell completely stops and the script can't be continued. Can this script maybe be changed so that it restarts itself - including the import of the credentials - instead of just failing?

The script is as follows:

```
param([string]$CSVFileName,[string]$EmailAddress,[string]$Username,[string]$Password,[string]$Domain,[bool]$Impersonate,[string]$EwsUrl,[string]$EWSManagedApiPath);
 
#
# Import-CalendarCSV.ps1
#
# By David Barrett, Microsoft Ltd. Use at your own risk.
# C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin

Function ShowParams()
{
    Write-Host "Import-CalendarCSV -CSVFileName <string> -EmailAddress <string>";
    Write-Host "                   [-Username <string> -Password <string> [-Domain <string>]]";
    Write-Host "                   [-Impersonate <bool>]";
    Write-Host "                   [-EwsUrl <string>]";
    Write-Host "                   [-EWSManagedApiPath <string>]";
    Write-Host "";
    Write-Host "Required:";
    Write-Host " -CSVFileName : Filename of the CSV file to import appointments for this user from.";
    Write-Host " -EmailAddress : Mailbox SMTP email address";
    Write-Host "";
    Write-Host "Optional:";
    Write-Host " -Username : Username for the account being used to connect to EWS (if not specified, current user is assumed)";
    Write-Host " -Password : Password for the specified user (required if username specified)";
    Write-Host " -Domain : If specified, used for authentication (not required even if username specified)";
    Write-Host " -Impersonate : Set to $true to use impersonation.";
    Write-Host " -EwsUrl : Forces a particular EWS URl (otherwise autodiscover is used, which is recommended)";
    Write-Host " -EWSManagedApiDLLFilePath : Full and path to the DLL for EWS Managed API (if not specified, default path for v1.1 is used)";
    Write-Host "";
}

$RequiredFields=@{
    "Subject" = "Subject";
    "StartDate" = "Start Date";
    "StartTime" = "Start Time";
    "EndDate" = "End Date";
    "EndTime" = "End Time"
}
 
# Check email address
# if (!$EmailAddress)
# {
#   ShowParams;
#    throw "Required parameter EmailAddress missing";
# }
 
# CSV File Checks
if (!$CSVFileName)
{
    ShowParams;
    throw "Required parameter CSVFileName missing";
}
if (!(Get-Item -Path $CSVFileName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
    throw "Unable to open file: $CSVFileName";
}
 
# Import CSV File
try
{
    $CSVFile = Import-Csv -Path $CSVFileName;
}
catch { }
if (!$CSVFile)
{
    Write-Host "CSV header line not found, using predefined header: Subject;StartDate;StartTime;EndDate;EndTime";
    $CSVFile = Import-Csv -Path $CSVFileName -header Subject,StartDate,StartTime,EndDate,EndTime;
}

# Check file has required fields
foreach ($Key in $RequiredFields.Keys)
{
    if (!$CSVFile[0].$Key)
    {
        # Missing required field
        throw "Import file is missing required field: $Key";
    }
}
 
# Check EWS Managed API available
 if (!$EWSManagedApiPath)
 {
     $EWSManagedApiPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
 }
 if (!(Get-Item -Path $EWSManagedApiPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
 {
     throw "EWS Managed API could not be found at $($EWSManagedApiPath).";
 }
 
# Load EWS Managed API
 [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($EWSManagedApiPath);
 
# Create Service Object.  We only need Exchange 2007 schema for creating calendar items (this will work with Exchange>=12)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2)

# Set credentials if specified, or use logged on user.
 if ($Username -and $Password)
 {
     if ($Domain)
     {
         $service.Credentials = New-Object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials($Username,$Password,$Domain);
     } else {
         $service.Credentials = New-Object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials($Username,$Password);
     }
     
} else {
     $service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true;
 }
 

    # Set EWS URL if specified, or use autodiscover if no URL specified.
if ($EwsUrl)
{
    $service.URL = New-Object Uri($EwsUrl);
}
else
{
    try
    {
        Write-Host "Performing autodiscover for $EmailAddress";
        $service.AutodiscoverUrl($EmailAddress, {$true});
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
    

 
# Bind to the calendar folder
 

# Parse the CSV file and add the appointments
foreach ($CalendarItem in $CSVFile)
{ 
    # Create the appointment and set the fields
    $NoError=$true;

    if ($Impersonate)
    {
        $service.ImpersonatedUserId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $CalendarItem."Email");
    }
    
    
    try {
        $CalendarFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarFolder]::Bind($service, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar);
    } catch {
        throw;
    }

    try
    {
        $Appointment = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment($service);
        $Appointment.Subject=$CalendarItem."Subject";
        $StartDate=[DateTime]($CalendarItem."StartDate" + " " + $CalendarItem."StartTime");
        $Appointment.Start=$StartDate;
        $EndDate=[DateTime]($CalendarItem."EndDate" + " " + $CalendarItem."EndTime");
        $Appointment.End=$EndDate;
            $Appointment.LegacyFreeBusyStatus = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LegacyFreeBusyStatus]::Busy;
            $Appointment.IsAllDayEvent= $CalendarItem."IsAllDayEvent";
            $Appointment.IsReminderSet= $CalendarItem."IsReminderSet";
    }
    catch
    {
        # If we fail to set any of the required fields, we will not write the appointment
        $NoError=$false;
    }
    
    # Check for any other fields
    foreach ($Field in ($CalendarItem | Get-Member -MemberType Properties))
    {
        if (!($RequiredFields.Keys -contains $Field.Name))
        {
            # This is a custom (optional) field, so try to map it
            try
            {
                $Appointment.$($Field.Name)=$CalendarItem.$($Field.Name);
            }
            catch
            {
                # Failed to write this field
                Write-Host "Failed to set custom field $($Field.Name)" -ForegroundColor yellow;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($NoError)
    {
        # Save the appointment
        $Appointment.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendInvitationsMode]::SendToNone)
        Write-Host "Created $($CalendarItem."Subject")" -ForegroundColor green;
    }
    else
    {
        # Failed to set a required field
        Write-Host "Failed to create appointment: $($CalendarItem."Subject")" -ForegroundColor red;
    }
}
```

And the following script is used in order to login to exchange online, clear appointments and then call the script above in order to create new appointments:

```
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

$AdminName = “XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.COM”
$Pass = Get-Content “C:\Scripte\CalendarUpdate\cred.txt” | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $Pass
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session

$TCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $AdminName, $Pass
$TPassword = $TCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$Emails = import-csv "C:\Scripte\CalendarUpdate\Users.csv"

ForEach ($i in $Emails) {
    $TEMP = Search-Mailbox $i.Emails -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Frei/Abwesend - Automatische Anlage"' -SearchDumpster:$false -EstimateResultOnly
    While($TEMP.ResultItemsCount -ne 0){
        Search-Mailbox $i.Emails -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Frei/Abwesend - Automatische Anlage"' -SearchDumpster:$false -DeleteContent -Force
        $TEMP = Search-Mailbox $i.Emails -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Frei/Abwesend - Automatische Anlage"' -SearchDumpster:$false -EstimateResultOnly
    }
    $userfilename = 'C:\Scripte\CalendarUpdate\Users\' + $i.Emails + '.csv'
    C:\Scripte\CalendarUpdate\Import-CalendarCSV.ps1 -CSVFileName $userfilename -Username XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.com -Password $TPassword -Impersonate $true -EwsUrl https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx -EWSManagedApiPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
    Remove-Item $userfilename
}

stop-Process -Name powershell
```

I really hope anyone here can help me with this! Thanks a lot in advance.
Kind regards
Tim

Answer (score 0):

First, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392948/7411885) similar question:

> The first place to start is to get the latest version of the EWS
> Managed API from Github https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api .
> The version you're using [2.2.0] hasn't been update since 2015 which is when
> Microsoft stopped releasing compiled versions of that library. However
> the code has been updated with numerous bug fixes on GitHub

You can add a retry loop to your second script if the issue is usually temporary:

```
$retries = 0
While ($retries -lt 3) {
  Try   {
    C:\Scripte\CalendarUpdate\Import-CalendarCSV.ps1 @params
    $retries = 3
  }
  Catch { $retries += 1 }
}
```

If those suggestions don't work, which line of the main script is failing? What is the exact error message?

This can be caused by a variety of issues in azureAd or O365, usually something failing to sync properly to O365, so check for errors on the server side as well.

**[Edit]** From the error in your comment, it looks like the issue is probably related to session timeouts or otherwise getting throttled by EXO. You may want to try the following module created by the [Exchange Team](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/324116):

[**RobustCloudCommand**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RobustCloudCommand/2.0.1) - [Github](https://github.com/Canthv0/RobustCloudCommand): Function `Start-RobustCloudCommand` is a  wrapper script that tries to ensure that a script block successfully finishes execution in O365 against a large object count.

**[Edit]**
In response to your comment about using `-credential` for basic auth, I did the following in `RobustCloudCommand.psm1` (Located at `(Get-Module RobustCloudCommand).path`):

```
#lines 104-105

[String]$UserPrincipalName,  ## Removed Mandatory
[pscredential]$credential,   ## Added -credential parameter


#lines 256-260:

# Create the session
Write-Log "Connecting to Exchange Online"
if ($credential) {Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $credential}
elseif ($UserPrincipalName) {Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -ShowBanner:$false}
else {Write-Error 'Either -Credential or -UserPrincipalName must be used to create a session'}
```

Comment: Hi Cpt. Whale, thanks for your feedback! I used the following lines of code in order to update EWS: 1) Register-PackageSource -provider NuGet -name nugetRepository -location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2    2) Install-Package Exchange.WebServices.Managed.Api . Looks like the update worked -> new version is: 2.2.1.2 . Is this the right one? I also implemented your lines of code. I'll let you know if the script runs fine the next times! Can we maybe add some additional lines of code so that if the connection gets lost, the script imports the login data again? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. Yesterday, the script worked fine on the first try. Today, the script failed again. Error message (translated from German -> I can't tell what the exact error description would be in English):
"Error when running command on remote server. Error Message: The E/A process was canceled due to end of thread or application condition. You can find more info in the help topic 'about_remote_troubleshooting'. Operation stopped: (outlook.office365.com:String) PSRemotingTransportException. JobFailure. PSComutername: outlook.office365.com.". I really need help

Comment: PS: The popup windows prompting to enter the login credentials was displayed.

Comment: @TimBauer I've added another suggestion based on that error, which should help allow a longer exo script to finish without a `while` loop, but I haven't used it myself. Do you expect the password/credentials to change in between commands? Why re-import them?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. The "install-module" command just needs to be run once, right? Where shall I put the "Start-RobustCloudCommand"? Anywhere in the second script? Which of the parameters of the cmdlet will I need?

Comment: Think I managed to implement it correctly :) Lets hope that the script now runs fine for some days! BUT I still have an issue: According to https://github.com/Canthv0/RobustCloudCommand , there should be a parameter for the credentials. But when I use this parameter (-Credential), the script fails with an error, saying that there is no such parameter. But if I don't enter this parameter, I am prompted to enter credentials, what I obviously do not want as this script should execute itself automatically. Any idea?

Comment: @TimBauer I found the author removed `-credential` at one point. I readded it manually and it seems to work fine. I might create a pull request later if I have time, but in the meantime I've added it to my answer.

Comment: It looks like for usage, you want to wrap each of your individual exchange-facing commands in the Robust command. It will be much slower, but ideally it also shouldn't fail.

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly! Thanks a lot. I think the problem was solved :) Thanks a lot for your help!